# Active property in tabset not working properly

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

By default the active property of tabset is blank(null) and when we set its property to `true` it is switched automatically. But when we are setting it to `null` again and then again setting it to `true` it is not getting switched. I have even displayed the active value in a `<p>` tag.

```
<pre>{{state_tab}}</pre>
<div class="ui-tab-container">
    <tabset>
        <tab heading="Region Wise" index="0" active="region_wise" ng-click="regionClicked()" style="border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;">
        </tab >
        <tab heading="Branch Wise" index="1" style="border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;" active="state_tab">
        </tab>
        <tab heading="City Wise" index="2" style="border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;" active="city_tab">
        </tab>
        <tab heading="Counter Wise" index="3" style="border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;" active="counter_tab">
        </tab>
    </tabset>
    <p>I am changing the value of state_tab to "" on the click of region tab</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using [angular-ui-bootstrap tabs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs) ?

Comment: duh! yeah......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have some old version of tabset. As described in the [documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs) the `active` attribute is on the `uib-tabset` element. E.g.

```
<uib-tabset active="currentTabIndex">
    <uib-tab heading="Region Wise" index="0" classes="my-tab">Region content</uib-tab>
    <!-- other tabs here -->
</uib-tabset>
```

See this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yT1pABVjYcaYzxNhPAaC?p=preview) with your example.

Comment: Thanks a lot man.But can you tell me for which version of angular and angular ui-bootstrap it works...I cant see any tabs when I replace <tabset> with <uib-tabset>...I have done some digging and I think it is mainly because of the conflicting versions of angular and ui bootstrap.

Comment: `uib-` prefix has been introduced for v0.14.0. Look at [the migration guide](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/wiki/Migration-guide-for-prefixes) for more information.

Comment: well in my case, I had trouble navigating though tabs programmatically even if I had latest angular files.
your PLNKR helped me fixed the issue. so +1 from me as well :)

Answer (score 0):

**Check out this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/CDI4Uv1sI8Q9Hx2Yc3Tp?p=preview)**

The `active` attribute should be added to the `tabset` directive. Its value should be the index of the tab to display. For more details, check out [Angular UI Bootstrap - Tabs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs)